# cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' asp.net.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am completely new In .NET.and i am just trying to achieve data annotation validation on client side.For that i search on net and found some solution.
about client side validation.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/556995/ASP-NET-MVC-interview-questions-with-answers

i just follow those steps.my code =>(include js files in bundle(WEB.OPTIMIZATION)) code below---

```
.Include("~/Content/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
```

and my view --

```
        @using something
        @model Vendor
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Add Vendor";
            ViewBag.Description = "TSMS-admin";
        }

        @section PageDescription{
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>
                    @ViewBag.Title
                    <small>@ViewBag.Description</small>
                </h1>
            </section>
        }

        @section Scripts{
            @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
            {
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        CustomMessage('Error', '@ViewBag.Message', 'Close');
                    });
                </script>
            }
        }


        <div class="row .col">
            <div style="margin-top:20px" class="mainbox col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "AddVendorForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.EnableClientValidation()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.adding_date, new { @Value = System.DateTime.Now })

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">Add A New Vendor</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body col-md-12">
                            <div>
                                <img class="center-block" style="border-radius: 3px;height: 200px;width: 200px;" id="venpic" src="~/Content/img/tsms/default/upload.png"><br><br /><br />
                                <label style="border-radius: 2px;" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-primary btn-load btn-lg" data-loading-text="Uploadinging Picture...">
                                    <input autocomplete="off" required name="pic_path" id="ifile_img" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg" onchange="readURL(this,'#venpic')" type="file" style="display: none;">Choose Pic
                                </label>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pic_path, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <br /><br /><br />
                            <div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.heading, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @class = "form-control", @id = "VendorName", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.heading), @autocomplete = "on", @onkeyup = "uppercase(this)" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.heading, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(mode => mode.body, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @class = "form-control", @id = "VendorDetails", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.body), @autocomplete = "on" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.body, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                    <input onclick="d()" type="button" id="AddVendor" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" /> | @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Manage")
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

problem is when i just wants to add `@Html.EnableClientValidation()` it showing me some kind of error like below...

[image: Problem]
how can i solve my problem.also the steps i am following to achieve data annotation validation on client side i it right/or i need to something else to achive this ---like `@Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript()`
is it necessary to acieve this...
.net MVC expert please help me......

Comment: `void` isn't a type. It's void - there is no result. The syntax you used is meant for *functions*, ie for methods that return results

Comment: To just fix the void to object issue, you can use `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set `@Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript()` and `@Html.EnableClientValidation()` in every view, just put this in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Hope you have set annotation attributes on you model properties.
Also, run below script after your form loads:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form = $('form')//Give Id prop to your from
form.removeData("validator")
form.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
});
<script>
```

Comment: i have some code in web config like `  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>`

Comment: Also -- How can i Understand That it is working properly.because after submit the form also give me error/warning from mode using server side validation....

Comment: jquery validation should work at client side and you shouldn't reach server side code if form has errors. So, put break point in your controller function Add and try to submit invalid form.

Answer (score 0):

Look you can add this code like this

```
@(ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = true)
```

or you can achieve the same result as following :

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

Or in mvc you don't need to mention this on view page you just add it into web config file like this :

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```